# Node.js Overriding Config in Module

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, configuration

So I want to break out parts of my application into different modules so they can be shared by other applications I'm working on. More specifically I want to break out my data layer.

My question is, if I have my database connection information in my Model-Module and import it is there a way for me to override the config if I want to point to a different database? Or is the only way to do this using environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple configuration files and in command line provide the envoirment variable to tell node which configuration file he can pick.
this is a boilerplate project which manages configuration files.

https://github.com/jpotts18/mean-stack-relational